# Why does the iOS app want to know my location?

Tags: support, ios-app

[image]

Why? What will happen if I disable it?

Comment: Wait, why you ask? Try disabling :D

Comment: For comparison, Android app v1.0.78beta doesn't (or probably *haven't*) ask for location permission...

Comment: I assume they [planned to use it for Jobs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223269/careers-should-be-smarter-about-using-location), to show more relevant ads, and at some point decided to drop that.

Comment: I don't see this in the latest version from TestFlight.  While using the app, were you asked to give your location?

Comment: @JAL nor do I. I asked it in Dec of the 2015... many iterations happened between then and now.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, currently there is no need to access location info in the app:

> [image: access]

- App Version: 1.6.3.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Cool, the question might then by "what changed?"